# Keyword Text Indexing in Text files, PDF files and Doc/Docx files in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing

I need to search and index resumes in txt, pdf and doc/docx format by keywords such as `Ruby on Rails'. I need help selecting and using the appropriate gems. I've started using sunspot 1.3.* but I can do only indexing on models. I could not find anything on how to index keywords from txt, pdf or doc files using sunspot_rails. Does anybody know how to configure sunspot to index through files attached?

Answer (score 2):

Try,Solr to index rich text document

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRichDocuments

http://solr.pl/en/2011/04/04/indexing-files-like-doc-pdf-solr-and-tika-integration/ for